# How to convert log4j StringMatchFilter to log4j2?

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm currently facing a problem to convert the StringMatchFilter from Log4j to Log4j2. I couldn't find any other filter in version 2, so I'm kinda stuck here.

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=false
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.filter.1.StringToMatch=Could not remove JaloSession 
JaloSession
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using MarkerFilter. MarkerFilter will do same job. Example:

```xml
<Filters>
    <MarkerFilter marker="STR1" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    <MarkerFilter marker="Str2" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
</Filters>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [`RegexFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#MarkerFilter) for this.

Something like:

```xml
<RegexFilter regex=".*Could not remove JaloSession.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
```